# Characterizing open countable subsets of the Cantor set

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

The Cantor-Bendixson theorem implies that any closed subset of the Cantor set $\mathcal{C}$ can be described as a disjoint union of a set $\mathcal{C}_c$ that is homeomorphic to the original Cantor set, and a countable open set $\mathcal{C}_o$.

The following [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57260/subsets-of-the-cantor-set), and the referenced work by Schoenberg & Grunhage therein, implies that all noncompact open subsets of the Cantor set are homeomorphic to the Cantor set minus a point—say, $\mathcal{C}/ \{ 0\}$. But this would mean that $\mathcal{C}_o$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal{C}/ \{ 0\}$, which would imply the Cantor set minus a point is countable, which seems strange.

Is this true, or am I missing something?

Comment: A countable open non-empty subset of $C$ has an isolated point by Baire, but this would have been isolated in $C$ as well, contradiction. So open + countable means empty.

Comment: "But this would mean..." is the incorrect part. E.g. you can do a kind of shuffle of the pieces of $C\setminus \{0,1\}$ to get a homeomorphism to $C\setminus \{0\}.$ Another counter-intuitive result is that the 3 real subspaces $\Bbb Q\cap [0,1],\,\Bbb Q\cap [0,1),\,\Bbb Q\cap (0,1)$ are homeomorphic to each other ( but the homeomorphisms do not preserve order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "countable open set $\mathcal C_o$" is not open as a subset of the cantor set $\mathcal C$, it is open as a subset of the set that can be written as $\mathcal C_c \sqcup \mathcal C_o$. Non-empty open subsets of Cantor space $\mathcal C$ are never countable.

Comment: Thanks—I'm guessing that means that the Cantor-Bendixson theorem does not imply that $\mathcal C = \mathcal C_c \sqcup \mathcal C_o$ then.

Answer (score 0):

The Cantor-Bendixsson theorem says that $C$ is a union of it's scattered part (open) and its perfect part (closed). The scattered part here is empty (as $C$ has no isolated points, and $C'=\emptyset$, and there is no scattering part) and it's already perfect. The theorem is valid but void here.

If $O \subseteq C$ is an open non-compact subset, it's locally compact (being open in compact) so it has a one-point compactification $\alpha O = O \cup \{\infty\}$. This is compact metric totally disconnected and has no isolated points so is homeomorphic to $C$ by Brouwer's theorem and so $O$ is homeomorphic to $C$ minus (any) point (by homogeneity).